# unsigned integer vs %u

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, integer

I am getting some hex parameters from my Bluetooth Low Energy sensor.

When i print the parameters on screen by invoke:

```
char * gotData = getTheData();
NSLog(@"My data: %u", gotData[1]);
```

The printing actually convert the hex representation to decimal.

My data in `gotData` are char with representation of Hex. e.g.

```
gotData = [0xFA, 0xCC];
```

I want to assign the integer value (the `0xFA`) to any object in objective-c/iOS.

Which one is the one to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data isn't stored in hex vs int vs whatever.  It's stored in bits, plain and simple.  How it's *presented* is up to how you describe it when you reference and display the bits.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about a hex "presentation". That is more correct than you might think. It is one possible presentation of the digital data. Char may be represented by `0xFA`. `%u` as such does not present the data in hex format. However, there is nothing converted. `0xFA` is simply identical with 250, just a different REPRESENTATION.

`NSNumber` is an apropriate object for storing numerical values. Whether it is advisable in your case depends on how you want to process it further.

Your data in gotData is not represented at all. It is just an octet stream. Digital data. The underlying type of data our whole industry works with.

If you want to present it hex using `NSLog` then try `%x` or `%X`.